# Android ActionMode styling, cannot set menu item colour

Tags: android, styling, android-styles, android-actionmode

I am trying to set the text colour for all the text inside a `ActionMode` in android. I have found ways to change `TitleTextColor` and `SubTitleTextColor` but I cannot find a way to style the actual non-collapsed menu item text color.

I am using the `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar` using the `statSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback)` to display the action mode.

Thanks in advance,

Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="ThemeName" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I have tried this but this also changes the colour of the menu items in the toolbar... Ideally I would want white text for the toolbar and black text for the actionMode. Is there a way to just single out the actionMode?

Comment: actionbar and toolbar are in the same place. what do you mean!?

Comment: I'm trying to style the colour of the menu items in the ActionMode only, which appears when items are selected in the application (using `Activity.startSupportActionMode(ActionMode.Callback)`). `actionMenuTextColor` changes the colour for both the ActionBar/Toolbar and the ActionMode.

Answer (score 0):

I used the iconTint attribute to style the menu items. Grab the xml file you use to inflate the menu then add the following attribute for each menu items that you want to style.

`android:iconTint="#fff"`

The above line of code will render the icons white. It's better to use your theme's color in styling.